# Error TS2342: An index expression argument must be of type 'string', 'number', or 'any'

Tags: typescript

I have some places in my code that look like this:

```
var array = [];
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
array[myObject] = "something";
```

Basically I'm using objects as keys in my array. I did not think much about it since it feels natural, the code compiles fine, and I have not encountered any bugs because of this.

Today I made a code push on an unrelated section of the code and Travis complained:

```
error TS2342: An index expression argument must be of type 'string', 'number', or 'any'.
```

on the line `array[myObject] = "something";`

I believe this is due to a recent update of `tsc`. Anyway, it brings this problem to my attention, and now I'm not sure what I've been doing is correct:

- What happens when you use objects as array keys? Do they get converted into string? If so, is the string made from an object supposed to be unique (like the hash value of the object)?
- In short, am I doing it the wrong way? If so, what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Basically I'm using objects as keys in my array.

Bad idea. JavaScript doesn't support objects as keys. It calls `toString` on objects to get a string representation before indexing.

Fix : use a `makeString` function. Checkout : https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections#a-sample-on-dictionary for an example

Answer (score 3):

All keys (*all* keys) of objects in JavaScript are strings. The default behavior of objects in JavaScript, when converted to a string, is to produce "[object Object]". I'm kind of surprised you haven't hit a bug with this yet, since it is entirely broken to use objects as keys:

```
class MyClass { }
var array = [];
var myObject1 = new MyClass();
var myObject2 = new MyClass();
array[myObject1] = "something";
array[myObject2] = "something else";
// Prints "[object Object]"
console.log(Object.keys(array).join(','));
// Prints "something else", not "something"
console.log(array[myObject1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the reasons given in the accepted answer, using class instances as an object key isn't great.  However, if you **DO** need to make it work, this is how you do it.

```
class MyClass { }
var array = [];
const myObject = new MyClass();
array[<string> myObject] = "something";
```

Notice how I've defined `<string>` before the myObject. It doesn't change how the Typescript compiles (see below), but it does change how Typescript interprets it.

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
    }
    return MyClass;
}());
var array = [];
var myObject = new MyClass();
array[myObject] = "something";
```